# Local Storage not working on my little project

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, local-storage

i hope someone can help me with this issue. Im working on this personal todo app, and everything was going fine until i tried to save my tasks in Local Storage. Im setting a line of code at line 74 to do so, and i works ok.

But from line 29 to line 45 im trying to print all the tasks that are previously saved when content is loaded, but doesnt work at all. I also realized that it's not setting the empty array [ ]; If i delete everything in local storage and reload, it does not set the empty array in local storage.

I also realized it throws an error in the stackoverflow console and that's why i had to comment that piece of code, but in the browser it shows no error at all without commenting that piece of code.

thanks for reading!

```js
// Javascript Input Form

    const form = {
        taskname: '',
        description: '',
        time1: '',
        time2: ''
    }

    // Validar
    
    // Variables

    const inputName = document.querySelector('#taskname');
    const inputDescription = document.querySelector('#description');
    const inputTime1 = document.querySelector('#time1');
    const inputTime2 = document.querySelector('#time2');
    const createButton = document.querySelector('#create');
    const cancelButton = document.querySelector('#cancel');
    const mainForm = document.querySelector('form');
    const closeButton = document.querySelector('#close-button');
    const formContainer = document.querySelector('#create-task-container');
    const emptyButton = document.querySelector('.section-empty');
    const ctaButton = document.querySelector('.cta');
    const section3 = document.querySelector('.section-3')
    
    //MAIN ARRAY

// HERE COMES THE ISSUE

    // let tasks = [];
    // let tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) || [];
    
    /*document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) || [];
        
        // if(localStorage.getItem('tasks')){
        //     tasks.map((tasks) => {
        //         imprimirTask(tasks);
        //     });
        // };
    });*/
    
// ENDS ISSUE 

    // Eventos

    mainForm.addEventListener('submit', crearTask);
    inputName.addEventListener('blur', validarForm);
    inputDescription.addEventListener('blur', validarForm);
    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', cerrarForm);
    closeButton.addEventListener('click', cerrarForm);
    emptyButton.onclick = () => aparecer();
    ctaButton.onclick = () => aparecer();


    // Funciones

    function crearTask(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('creando task');

        const datosTask = {
            id: Date.now(),
            name: inputName.value.trim(),
            description: inputDescription.value.trim(),
            time1: inputTime1.value.trim(),
            time2: inputTime2.value.trim(),
            allDayTask: false,
            isCompleted: false,
        }
        tasks = [...tasks, datosTask];
        // localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
        console.log(tasks);
        mainForm.reset();
        quitarEstilos();
        imprimirTask(e, datosTask);
    };

    function imprimirTask(e, tasks){
        const taskEl = document.createElement('div');
        taskEl.classList.add('task');
        taskEl.setAttribute('id', tasks.id);
        console.log('div creado');
        cerrarForm(e);
        if(tasks.isCompleted){
            taskEl.classList.add('done');
        }

        const taskElHtml = `
                <div class="header-task">
                <div>
                    <h4 contenteditable="true" class="name">${tasks.name}</h4>
                    <span>${tasks.description}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ${tasks.isCompleted ? 'checked' : ''}>  
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-task">
                <div>
                    <p>Today</p>
                    <span>${tasks.time1} - ${tasks.time2}</span>
                </div>
                <button id="trash">
                    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M16 6V5.2C16 4.0799 16 3.51984 15.782 3.09202C15.5903 2.71569 15.2843 2.40973 14.908 2.21799C14.4802 2 13.9201 2 12.8 2H11.2C10.0799 2 9.51984 2 9.09202 2.21799C8.71569 2.40973 8.40973 2.71569 8.21799 3.09202C8 3.51984 8 4.0799 8 5.2V6M10 11.5V16.5M14 11.5V16.5M3 6H21M19 6V17.2C19 18.8802 19 19.7202 18.673 20.362C18.3854 20.9265 17.9265 21.3854 17.362 21.673C16.7202 22 15.8802 22 14.2 22H9.8C8.11984 22 7.27976 22 6.63803 21.673C6.07354 21.3854 5.6146 20.9265 5.32698 20.362C5 19.7202 5 18.8802 5 17.2V6" stroke="#888888" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>   
            </div>
        `;
        taskEl.innerHTML = taskElHtml;
        section3.appendChild(taskEl);
    }

    function validarForm(e){
        validarTodo();
        if(e.target.value.trim() === ''){
            e.target.classList.add('failed');
            alerta("This field can't be empty", e.target.parentElement);
            form[e.target.id] = ''
            return;
        }
        
        form[e.target.id] = e.target.value.trim();
        e.target.classList.remove('failed');
        e.target.classList.add('succeed');
        quitarAlerta(e.target.parentElement);
        // validarTodo();
        console.log(form);
    };

    function alerta(mensaje, referencia){
        quitarAlerta(referencia);
        const createSpan = document.createElement('span');
        createSpan.textContent = mensaje;
        createSpan.classList.add('failed-span');
        referencia.appendChild(createSpan);

    };

    function quitarAlerta(referencia){
        const alerta = referencia.querySelector('.failed-span')
        if(alerta){
            alerta.remove();
        };
    };

    function cerrarForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        formContainer.classList.add('hide');
        createButton.classList.remove('click-me');
        createButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            formContainer.style.display = 'none';
            formContainer.style.opacity = '0';
            formContainer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            formContainer.classList.remove('hide');
            console.log('Cerró todo');
        }, 450);
        mainForm.reset();
        resetObj();
        console.log(form);
        quitarEstilos();
        
    }

    function validarTodo(){
        if(inputName.value.trim() === '' || inputDescription.value.trim() === ''){
            createButton.style.opacity = '.8';
            console.log('Cta NO está disponible');
            createButton.classList.remove('click-me');
            createButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
        } else{
            console.log('Cta está disponible');
            // createButton.style.opacity = '1';
            createButton.classList.add('click-me');
            createButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
        };
    };

    function quitarEstilos(){
        if(inputName.classList.contains('succeed') || inputName.classList.contains('failed')){
            inputName.classList.remove('succeed');
            inputName.classList.remove('failed');
            quitarAlerta(document);
            // return;
        }
        if(inputDescription.classList.contains('succeed') || inputDescription.classList.contains('failed')){
            inputDescription.classList.remove('succeed');
            inputDescription.classList.remove('failed');
            quitarAlerta(document);
            return;
        }
    }

    function aparecer(){
        formContainer.style.opacity = '1';
        formContainer.style.visibility = 'visible';
        formContainer.style.display = 'grid';
        inputName.focus();
    };

    function resetObj(){
        form.taskname = '';
        form.description = '';
        form.time1 = '';
        form.time2 = '';
    }
```

```css
:root{
    --tamaño-1: 28px;
    --tamaño-2: 19px;
    --tamaño-3: 18px;
    --tamaño-4: 16px;
    --verde-fondo: #205b52;
    --verde-claro: #D3FEE4;
    --azul-letra: #2368dd;
    --color-texto-1: #000;
    --color-texto-2: #888888;
    --color-texto-3: #bababa;
    --blanco-fondo: #fff;

    --rojo-fondo: #ffeaef;
    --rojo: #f7345e;
    --verde-input-fondo: #e7f5ec;
    --verde: #34d39d;

}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Figtree', sans-serif;
    cursor: default;
}

button{
    background: none;
    border:none;
}
path{
    transition: .3s;
}
/* body{
    background-color: #d0d1da;
} */

.main-div{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 40px 30px;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 35px;
}


main .header-2 .first{
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.section-1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1, h5{
    font-size: var(--tamaño-1);
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--color-texto-1);
}
h2{
    font-weight: 500;
}
h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
#cta{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    font-size: var(--tamaño-4);
    /* font-weight: 500; */
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: var(--verde-fondo);
    color: var(--blanco-fondo);
    border: none;
    transition: .3s;
}
#cta:is(:hover){
    opacity: .9 !important;
}

#plus{
    stroke: var(--azul-letra);
}

#trash:is(:hover) > svg >path{
    stroke: #f7345e;
}
.check:is(:hover) > svg >path{
    stroke: var(--verde-fondo);
}

.second{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 5px;
}

.second span{
    color: var(--color-texto-2);
    font-weight: 400;
}

.section-2{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.section-2 ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* font-weight: 500; */
    color: var(--color-texto-2);
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    gap: 15px;
}

.section-2 ul li{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 7px;
}
.section-2 ul li span{
    background-color: var(--azul-letra);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 45%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.section-2 ul #separador{
    width: 2px;
    background: var(--color-texto-3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 16px;
}


/* TASKS */

.task{
    background-color: var(--blanco-fondo);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.header-task{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-texto-3);
}
.header-task div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* gap: 5px; */
}
.header-task div span{
    color: var(--color-texto-2);
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: text;
}
.footer-task{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.footer-task div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
}
.footer-task button, .header-task div button{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.footer-task div p{
    color: var(--color-texto-2);
    font-size: 15px;
}

.footer-task div span{
    color: var(--color-texto-2);
    font-size: 15px;
}

h4, label{
    font-size: var(--tamaño-2);
    font-weight: 500;
}
h4{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: text;
}
h4[contenteditable]:hover{
    /* background-color: #f0faf9; */
    /* background-color: #B9F3D0; */
    background-color: #D3FEE4;
}
h4[contenteditable]:focus-visible, h4[contenteditable]:focus, h4[contenteditable]:active, h4[contenteditable]:focus-within{
    /* background-color: #f0faf9; */
    /* background-color: #B9F3D0; */
    background-color: #D3FEE4;
    outline: none;
}

/* // container cta */

.container{
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    gap: 7px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px dashed var(--color-texto-3);
    height: 30vh;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: .2s;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
}
.container p{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--verde-fondo);
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
.container:is(:hover){
    /* border: 2px dashed var(--color-texto-2); */
    border: 2px dashed var(--verde-fondo);
}

/* // Create task form */

.create-task{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 40px 30px;
    /* margin-top: 40px; */
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
.create-task div form div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}

.create-task div, button{
    /* display: grid; */
    place-content: start;
}
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "n n"
        "d d"
        "t1 t2"
        "r r"
        "b b";
    gap: 15px;
}
.name{
    grid-area: n;
}
.description{
    grid-area: d;
}
.time1{
    grid-area: t1;
}
.time2{
    grid-area: t2;
}
.grid-container .grid{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.header-form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between !important;
    align-items: center;
}
.header-form span{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
span:is(:hover) > svg >path{
    stroke: var(--color-texto-1);
}
label{
    font-size: 15px;
}
.radio{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: r;
    flex-direction: row !important;
}
.buttons{
    display: grid !important;
    grid-area: b;
    gap: 15px !important;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "create"
    "cancel";
    flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
    /* border-top: 1px solid var(--color-texto-3); */
}
.buttons button{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 13px 0px;
    background-color: var(--blanco-fondo);
    transition: .2s;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
#cancel{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: cancel;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid var(--color-texto-2);
    transition: .2s;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#cancel:is(:hover){
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 2px solid var(--color-texto-1);
}
#create{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: create;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 2px solid var(--verde-fondo);
    background-color: var(--verde-fondo);
    transition: .2s;
    color: var(--blanco-fondo);
    opacity: .8;
}
input{
    padding: 13px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid var(--color-texto-2);
    transition: .2s;
    background-color: var(--blanco-fondo);
    color: var(--color-texto-1);
    padding-left: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
input:focus-visible{
    outline: none;
}
input:focus{
    border: 2px solid var(--color-texto-1);
    background-color: var(--blanco-fondo);
}
input[placeholder]{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 13px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 2px solid var(--color-texto-2);
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="checkbox"]::before{
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='12' height='10' viexBox='0 0 12 10' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M10.5 1L4.5 9L1.5 5.5' stroke='%23fff' stroke-width='1.5' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    background-color: var(--verde-fondo);
    border-color: var(--verde-fondo);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before{
    transform: scale(1);
}

#create-task-container{
    
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    place-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

footer{
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: default;
}
footer p{
    color: var(--color-texto-2);
    font-size: 13px;
}
/* footer p span{
    text-decoration: underline;
} */

/* // Clases para javascript */




.done{
    background-color: var(--verde-claro) ;
}
.tacho{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.succeed{
    background-color: var(--verde-input-fondo);
    border: 2px solid var(--verde);
}
.hide{
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
.failed{
    background-color: var(--rojo-fondo);
    border: 2px solid var(--rojo);
}
.failed-span{
    color: var(--rojo);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: .2s;
}
/* .click-me{
    opacity: 1;
} */
.buttons button.click-me{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.buttons button.click-me:hover{
    opacity: .9 !important;
}







/* // Media Queries */

@media screen and (min-width: 550px){

    .buttons{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
        "cancel create"
        ;
    }

    .create-task{
        min-width: 500px;
    }
}

/* //Keyframes */

 @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
      opacity: .9;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
      opacity: .9;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@300;400;500;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>TicTac</h2>
        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M12 2V4M12 20V22M4 12H2M6.31412 6.31412L4.8999 4.8999M17.6859 6.31412L19.1001 4.8999M6.31412 17.69L4.8999 19.1042M17.6859 17.69L19.1001 19.1042M22 12H20M17 12C17 14.7614 14.7614 17 12 17C9.23858 17 7 14.7614 7 12C7 9.23858 9.23858 7 12 7C14.7614 7 17 9.23858 17 12Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        </svg>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="header-2">
            <div class="first">
                <h3>Today's Task</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="main-div">
                <div class="section-1">
                    <div class="second">
                        <h1>Today's Task</h1>
                        <span>Thursday, 18 May</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cta">
                        <button id="cta">
                            <svg id="plus" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M12 5V19M5 12H19" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                            </svg>
                         New Task</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="section-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>All</li>
                        <li id="separador"></li>
                        <li>Remaining</li>
                        <li>Completed</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="section-3">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="section-empty">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div>
                            <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M20 10.5V6.8C20 5.11984 20 4.27976 19.673 3.63803C19.3854 3.07354 18.9265 2.6146 18.362 2.32698C17.7202 2 16.8802 2 15.2 2H8.8C7.11984 2 6.27976 2 5.63803 2.32698C5.07354 2.6146 4.6146 3.07354 4.32698 3.63803C4 4.27976 4 5.11984 4 6.8V17.2C4 18.8802 4 19.7202 4.32698 20.362C4.6146 20.9265 5.07354 21.3854 5.63803 21.673C6.27976 22 7.11984 22 8.8 22H12M14 11H8M10 15H8M16 7H8M18 21V15M15 18H21" stroke="#205b52" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                            </svg> 
                        </div>
                        <p>Such empty. Get started by creating a new task</p>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <div id="create-task-container">
        <div class="create-task">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="header-form">
                    <h5>Create a Task</h5>
                    <span id="close-button">
                        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M18 6L6 18M6 6L18 18" stroke="#888888" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                        </svg>
                    </span>
        
                </div>
                <form class="grid">
                    <div class="name">
                        <label for="taskname">What's your goal today?</label>
                        <input id="taskname" placeholder="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <label for="description">Description</label>
                        <input id="description" placeholder="Add a short description to your task" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="time1">
                        <label for="time1">Time-From</label>
                        <input id="time1" type="time">
                    </div>
                    <div class="time2">
                        <label for="time2">Time-To</label>
                        <input id="time2" type="time">
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="radio">
                        <label for="radio">It's gonna be an all day task instead.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" disabled id="create">Create Task</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <!-- <p>Developed by <span>Gabriel Maestre.</span></p> -->
        <p>Developed by Gabriel Maestre.</p>
    </footer>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't comment out the code with the issue. The SO syntax highlighter greys it out, making it hard to read.

Comment: You're getting an error in SO because its snippet embedding code doesn't allow local storage.

Comment: `tasks = [...tasks, datosTask];` is usually written as `tasks.push(datosTask)`.

Comment: `imprimirTask()` takes 2 arguments. You're calling it with only 1 argument in the `tasks.map()` loop. You're missing the `e` argument.

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')||"[]");` prevents you parsing an empty key slot and throwing there.

Comment: I am going to guess that you are opening this HTML page directly (`file://...`) rather than hosting it on a local HTTP server. HTML files loaded from the local file system violate the "same origin" policy and thus are [not allowed to access Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#exceptions).

Comment: @JDB im opening the file from Live server extension. And following a youtube video, they also use that to open file and works perfectly. But mine doesn't work. I fixed the tasks.push( ), but still does not start with an empty array from the localStorage

Answer (score 0):

> I also realized that it's not setting the empty array [ ]; If i delete
> everything in local storage and reload, it does not set the empty
> array in local storage.

To achieve that, your script needs to:

1. check whether local storage is empty on page load;
2. set an empty array inside local storage if local storage is indeed empty on page load.

Currently, it's not doing either of the above.